# toString method added dynamically to project

Tags: java, aspectj, lombok

Is there any option to add Lombok's annotation `@ToString` dynamically (f.e. during building the code) to all classes from the custom package, f.e. `xxx.yyy.dao.*` ?

I've tried with aspect approach:

```
declare @type : xxx.yyy.dao.* : @lombok.ToString;
```

but i got

```
AJC compiler error: org.aspectj.weaver.patterns.DeclareAnnotation -> Index 1 out of bounds for length 1
```

I guess it is not allowed as lombok's annotations are also loaded kinda at same compilation time.

The goal is to have `toString()` method applied by default to all classes from the given package (in such case a developer doesn't need to remember to add `@ToString` manually to each class).

Comment: Are you aware that every class is inheriting toString() from java.lang.Object and overriding it using Lombok without having class' insights is of no benefit (or I don‘t get it)?

Comment: Without Lombok I get the `class name + hashcode` only. I'm aware of that, in most cases classes have fields

Comment: I see. But unfortunately I don‘t have a valid answer.

Comment: You can do this during build, similar to how maven or Gradle filters files to replace placeholders.

Comment: @AbhijitSarkar any working sample? (haven't found any with Lombok)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is (please read that page fully) and how it helps you get better help faster. A one-line code snippet is not debuggable. Please edit the question and show full classes (incl. package names and imports) for the aspect and at least one target class plus your build configuration (Maven, Gradle, Ant or command line you use for compilation). Or simply share a GitHub project link.

Answer (score 2):

I just noticed that you use a Lombok annotation, but those all have `SOURCE` retention. **It simply does not make any sense to declare a source-level annotation on woven byte code, it is paradoxical.** Nevertheless, the AspectJ weaver should be improved to show a proper warning instead of a spurious weaving error.

Actually, this is a known bug since 2011, which I just commented on your behalf:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=366085

In order to solve your problem, you either need to add a source-level preprocessing step to your build which kicks in even before Lombok, or you need to develop some kind of `ToStringAspect` which generates or intercepts `toString` methods on the fly, dynamically using reflection to iterate over instance fields and creating a meaningful string representation for them.